# Protractor failing because chrome requires google login

Tags: angular, google-chrome, typescript, protractor

My protractor tests were working fine a few weeks ago, but stopped working after no changes to my code.  I think google chrome has been updated though.

Suddenly, when I launch my tests, by typing "npm run e2e", the tests open the chrome browser (as usual) but now it forces me to login to my google account in chrome.  It looks like this:

[image: Chrome forcing me to sign in]

What do I do?

Here is how I have my browser config in protractor.conf.js

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [ "--window-size=800,600" ]
    }
},
```

Comment: what's your current chrome version? my chrome upgraded to latest 64.0.3282.140 has no such issue.  You can give a try to reinstall chrome

Comment: @yong I'm using the very latest chrome.  Yes, its 64.0.xxx.  I even tried uninstalling chrome, downloading it again today, and installing again today... same problem occurred.

Comment: I guess some profile files in user home not cleared after uninstall,  some one of those profile files includes the login setting. Another possibility is you need to use latest chromedriver to be compatible with latest chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Started to happen to me as well. I'm using version 81.0.4044.113.

A possible workaround is to run protractor in headless mode, meaning that the browser doesn't actually get opened.

Add the following args to your protractor config:

```
config.capabilities.chromeOptions = {
    args: [
      '--headless',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--disable-browser-side-navigation'
    ]
  }
```